# I can't set geolocater package with flutter project

Tags: flutter, google-maps

I am trying to setup the `geolocater` package in my flutter project. I have followed the documentation but it didn't work for me. This is the error I encountered:

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
A problem occurred configuring project ':geolocator_android'.
> Could not resolve all files for configuration ':geolocator_android:classpath'.
   > Could not find gradle-7.4.2.jar (com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.4.2).
```

This is what I modified in `build.gradle` file:

```
 compileSdkVersion 33
  minSdkVersion  20
  targetSdkVersion 33`
```

And in `AndroidManifest.xml` I have added the following:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_BACKGROUND_LOCATION" />
```

Comment: It looks like the error is caused by your gradle version. Can you check that out?